# Qt dialog accept and reject

Tags: qt, checkbox, textbox, dialog

I'm trying to implement the following thing: when a specific button is clicked, a new dialog appears where the user has to enter some information and to check/uncheck some checkboxes. Then the user can either click "OK" or "Cancel".

If he clicks "OK" the information he entered is checked for correctness. If something is not correct the dialog should appear again with a warning message and the user should correct/re-enter the information. I would like the information the user entered to be stored. So, if the information is not correct, the dialog should not "reset" to the initial state but keep the information the user entered.

If the user clicks "Cancel" some standard values are used further.

I almost got a solution, but it is not working properly. When using my solution: when I enter a wrong information and click "OK" a warning appears and the information is stored and I can edit it. But if I enter wrong information again and click "OK" again, then the wrong information is accepted. Please see my code below.

```
QDialog dialog(this);
QFormLayout form(&dialog);

form.addRow((new QLabel("Please enter the three questions for the P835 test. \n"
                        "Questions one and two will be permuted, \n "
                        "question three will not. Below each question enter \n"
                        "the rating scale starting with the best rating and \n"
                        "separate the ratings with a comma.")));
QList<QLineEdit *> fields;

    QLineEdit *lineEdit_Q1 = new QLineEdit(&dialog);
    lineEdit_Q1->setText("Bitte bewerten Sie die Signalqualität!");
    QString label_Q1 = QString("First question:");
    form.addRow(label_Q1, lineEdit_Q1);
    fields << lineEdit_Q1;

    QLineEdit *lineEdit_Q1_answer = new QLineEdit(&dialog);
    lineEdit_Q1_answer->setText("nicht verzerrt, leicht verzerrt, etwas verzerrt, ziemlich verzerrt, sehr verzerrt");
    QString label_Q1_answer = QString("Rating first question:");
    form.addRow(label_Q1_answer, lineEdit_Q1_answer);
    fields << lineEdit_Q1_answer;

QDialogButtonBox buttonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel, Qt::Horizontal, &dialog);
    form.addRow(&buttonBox);
    QObject::connect(&buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), &dialog, SLOT(accept()));
    QObject::connect(&buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), &dialog, SLOT(reject()));
    bool click = true;
    int code = dialog.exec();
    bool passed = true;
    while (click == true){
        passed = true;
        if (code == QDialog::Accepted) {
        // check if empty questions were entered
        if (lineEdit_Q1->text() == "" || lineEdit_Q2->text() == "" || lineEdit_Q3->text() == "") {
            QMessageBox msgBox;
            msgBox.setText("An error occured while entering questions for the P835 test");
            msgBox.setInformativeText("You can not enter empty questions! Please try again or click cancel to use the standard questions!");
            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
            msgBox.exec();
            passed = false;
            dialog.close();
            dialog.exec();
            break;
        }
        if (lineEdit_Q1_answer->text().split(",").size() != 5 || lineEdit_Q2_answer->text().split(",").size() != 5 || lineEdit_Q3_answer->text().split(",").size() != 5) {
            QMessageBox msgBox;
            msgBox.setText("An error occured while entering question ratings for the P835 test");
            msgBox.setInformativeText("You have to enter exactly 5 ratings for each question! Please try again or click cancel to use the standard ratings!");
            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
            msgBox.exec();
            passed = false;
            dialog.close();
            dialog.exec();
            break;
        }
        if (oneFileCheckBox->isChecked() && multipleFilesCheckBox->isChecked()) {
            QMessageBox msgBox;
            msgBox.setText("An error occured while setting up the P835 test...");
            msgBox.setInformativeText("You cannot check both boxes! Please select only one option for the files!");
            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
            msgBox.exec();
            passed = false;
            dialog.close();
            dialog.exec();
            break;
        }
        if (oneFileCheckBox->isChecked() == false && multipleFilesCheckBox->isChecked() == false) {
            QMessageBox msgBox;
            msgBox.setText("An error occured while setting up the P835 test...");
            msgBox.setInformativeText("You have to select one file option!");
            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
            msgBox.exec();
            passed = false;
            dialog.close();
            dialog.exec();
            break;
        }
        if (passed == true) {
            this->configMgr->setQuestions(lineEdit_Q1->text(), lineEdit_Q2->text(), lineEdit_Q3->text());
            this->configMgr->setAnswers(lineEdit_Q1_answer->text(), lineEdit_Q2_answer->text(), lineEdit_Q3_answer->text());
            if(oneFileCheckBox->isChecked() == true) {
                this->configMgr->fileOption = 0;
            }
            if(multipleFilesCheckBox->isChecked() == true) {
                this->configMgr->fileOption = 1;
            }
            QMessageBox msgBox;
            msgBox.setText("Success!");
            msgBox.setInformativeText("The questions and the question ratings have been set successfully!");
            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Information);
            msgBox.exec();
            dialog.close();
            click = false;
        }
        if (code == QDialog::Rejected) {
            this->configMgr->setQuestions(Q1_std, Q2_std, Q3_std);
            this->configMgr->setAnswers(Q1_std_answer, Q2_std_answer, Q3_std_answer);
            QMessageBox msgBox;
            msgBox.setText("Setting standard values...");
            msgBox.setInformativeText("Standard questions and ratings will be set. Click on the P835 button again to set questions and ratings manually!");
            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Information);
            msgBox.exec();
            dialog.close();
            click = false;
        }
        }
        if (code == QDialog::Rejected) {
            this->configMgr->setQuestions(Q1_std, Q2_std, Q3_std);
            this->configMgr->setAnswers(Q1_std_answer, Q2_std_answer, Q3_std_answer);
            QMessageBox msgBox;
            msgBox.setText("Setting standard values...");
            msgBox.setInformativeText("Standard questions and ratings will be set. Click on the P835 button again to set questions and ratings manually!");
            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Information);
            msgBox.exec();
            dialog.close();
            click = false;
        }
    }
```

In this example code I only put one text box where the user has to enter some information. I have six text boxes and two checkboxes.

I hope you can help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You should use validation with `QDialog::done(int r)` or a `QWizard`.  Qt makes this task relatively easy if you take the time to study the examples and documentation on it, but it does take time to learn it the first time.

### Validation with `QDialog::done(int r)`

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/8048-Validate-Data-in-QDialog

```
void DataSourceDlg::done(int r)
{
    if(QDialog::Accepted == r)  // ok was pressed
    {
        if(nodeLineEdit->text().size() > 3)   // validate the data somehow
        {
            QDialog::done(r);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            statusBar->setText("Invalid data in text edit...try again...");
            return;
        }
    }
    else    // cancel, close or exc was pressed
    {
        QDialog::done(r);
        return;
    }
}
```

Note that by subclassing `QDialog` and managing the `done` method you can prevent the dialog from closing and display a message.

### `QWizard` and `QWizardPage`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html#details

Using a `QWizard` is a little more work, but it is built around validation and ensuring the correct information is in the right boxes.

Basically you subclass QWizard and QWizard page, and then you implement `validatePage()` and some others methods and you follow the examples and it works flawlessly.  This used to be included in Qt Solutions and it was opened up a few years ago.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-classwizard-example.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-licensewizard-example.html

```
companyLabel = new QLabel(tr("&Company name:"));
companyLineEdit = new QLineEdit;
companyLabel->setBuddy(companyLineEdit);

emailLabel = new QLabel(tr("&Email address:"));
emailLineEdit = new QLineEdit;
emailLineEdit->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp(".*@.*"), this));
emailLabel->setBuddy(emailLineEdit);

postalLabel = new QLabel(tr("&Postal address:"));
postalLineEdit = new QLineEdit;
postalLabel->setBuddy(postalLineEdit);

registerField("details.company*", companyLineEdit);
registerField("details.email*", emailLineEdit);
registerField("details.postal*", postalLineEdit);
```

`*` makes a field mandatory.  `QRegExpValidator` makes sure the email address has an `@` sign in the middle.

### `QValidator` with `QLineEdit`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html#details

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-lineedits-example.html

```
    validatorLineEdit->setValidator(new QIntValidator(
        validatorLineEdit));

    validatorLineEdit->setValidator(new QDoubleValidator(-999.0,
        999.0, 2, validatorLineEdit));
```

### `QLineEdit::setInputMask(QString)`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop

```
    inputMaskLineEdit->setInputMask("");

    inputMaskLineEdit->setInputMask("+99 99 99 99 99;_");

    inputMaskLineEdit->setInputMask("0000-00-00");
    inputMaskLineEdit->setText("00000000");
    inputMaskLineEdit->setCursorPosition(0);

    inputMaskLineEdit->setInputMask(">AAAAA-AAAAA-AAAAA-AAAAA-AAAAA;#");
```

### Regular Expressions

RegEx is awesome.  Learning it is extremely useful (IMHO).  I really like the tools and cheatsheets provided by gskinner. http://regexr.com/

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexpvalidator.html#details

```
// regexp: optional '-' followed by between 1 and 3 digits
QRegExp rx("-?\\d{1,3}");
QValidator *validator = new QRegExpValidator(rx, this);

QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit(this);
edit->setValidator(validator);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! I just have some troubles getting it to work with the done() method. My QDialog is created in my main() function and therefore I cannot access the variables keeping the data, e.g. the lineEdit_Q1. And then, how do I call the done()-method? Just by using dialog.done(int r)?

Comment: Most of the time for validation to work, you need to subclass the dialog or wizard.  You can do this above your main, but creating another `.h` and `.cpp` for a custom dialog (or any customized `QWidget`) improves readability and maintainability.